# How to increase brightness of a highlighted text in a scanned image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, scanning, highlights

I'm currently scanning a few documents at the moment and have highlighted several parts of the text.

My scanner doesn't pick up the highlighted text very well and the highlighted areas are very faint.

Is it possible to use Photoshop to enhance the colour of the highlight?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Uploaded image for reference]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

- Select > Color Range...
- Use the eyedropper to click a Yellow area.
- Adjust the Fuzziness slider until it pretty much covers only that highlight.

[image: color range]

- Click OK

You will then have a selection of the highlight.
Simply apply an adjustment layer, such as Vibrance, to alter the highlight appearance.

[image: Vibrance]

Or even a Hue/Saturation adjustment to change the highlight color

[image: Hue/Saturation]